# Webgl Inspector does not display uniform values

Tags: webgl

I am new to shader programming and webgl, and am trying to use the Webgl inspector to debug a problem I am having. However, when I open the UI and select the shader program I wish to debug, no values show up for any of the uniforms, although the uniform name, type, and size show up fine for all my uniforms.

Does anyone know what may be wrong? I tried to see the values both when I froze my program and while it ran.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to see the uniform values is to capture a frame and look in the trace tab. This captures an entire frame, so you might have to do some digging to find the right draw call. Click the "i" to the right on the draw call instructions to get a better summary of what's been set for that particular draw call.

BTW: you cannot step through a program, unfortunately.